# How to center a text using coordinates and text length

Tags: php, laravel, coordinates, center, pdflib

I'm generating a certificate with a user name for a course platform. I want to center a text but **it is not centered at all, It starts in the middle but the text is moved** i. I'm using PHP 8.0 and the library [MPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/).
My code is the following:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['orientation' => 'L']);
$mpdf->setSourceFile('storage/' . $certificate->url); // absolute path to pdf file
$certificatePDf = $mpdf->importPage(1);

$mpdf->useTemplate($certificatePDf, 0, 0, null, null, true);
$pageSize = $mpdf->getTemplateSize($certificatePDf);
$textSize = strlen($name);
$mpdf->SetFont('Sanchez-Regular', '', 40,); 
$mpdf->SetY(130);
//centering the name on the pdf
$mpdf->WriteText($pageSize['width']/2 - $textSize/2  , 130, $name);
$mpdf->Output('newpdf.pdf');
```

My formula is the following: `$totalPageSize/2 - $textSize/2`.
An example:[image: formula result]
What else if left to center based on text length?

Comment: Use <p align="center"> Text </p> combination

Comment: I am calculating by coordinates

Comment: `$pageSize['width']` will likely be a rather large value, either in pixels or mm, I suppose? Your `$textSize` however is just the number of characters (or more precise, bytes) of your name value. `Erik Sanabria Martinez` is 22 characters, half of that is 11.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I read the documentation and i realized i was able to add text as a html. I just concatenated the name between a html tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mpdf allows to enter text in HTML, even if  you're trying to load a **pdf** or an HTML view as a template.

Here is what I did:
[My Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeIGD.png)